# Get rank of contestants from points table with additional and nested conditions

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

We're trying to calculate the rank of contestants for a specific contest, using the following select query. The `GROUP_CONCAT` workaround is actually a solution that was offered here on SO for a similar question.

However, as we added more conditions the query got long, untidy and is not DRY, I think as we have to repeat the same conditions for the `GROUP_CONCAT` subquery.

How can it be optimized? Or would a solution like programmatically calculate ranks and check conditions then populate the database, be the best solution in this case?

```
SELECT *,
  -- Get the rank of contestants
  FIND_IN_SET(`id`, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id` ORDER BY `points` DESC, `created`)
      FROM `contestants` `c2`

      -- The following query is exactly the same as the on in the main query bellow.
      WHERE `contest_id`=:contest_id
        AND EXISTS (
          SELECT `user_id`
          FROM `item`
          WHERE `user_id`=`c2`.`user_id`
            AND `product_id` IN (
              SELECT `id`
              FROM `product`
              WHERE `price`<=:max_price
                AND `available`=:available
            )
        )
        AND `state`=:state
        -- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    )
  ) AS `rank`
FROM `contestants`

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WHERE `contest_id`=:contest_id
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT `user_id`
    FROM `item`
    WHERE `user_id`=`c2`.`user_id`
      AND `product_id` IN (
        SELECT `id`
        FROM `product`
        WHERE `price`<=:max_price
          AND `available`=:available
      )
  )
  AND `state`=:state
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ORDER BY `rank` ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: MySQL user variables might scale better something like `SELECT *, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM contestants ORDER BY points DESC, created ASC, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r`

Comment: One of the subqueries uses a terrible algorithm for "groupwise max"; see the Tag I added.